# PLSQL DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE error When Using Variable Parameter

Tags: mysql, oracle, pass-through

I have a dblink connected to mysql called `times`.

I have a table name `test_tblOOHA_Master` with one record (see image below).

[image]

My code:

```
DECLARE 
    num_rows INTEGER;
    v_cursor   BINARY_INTEGER;
    nr INTEGER;

    -- BINDING VARIABLES            
    header_id INTEGER; 
    flow_status_code VARCHAR(500); 
    qry VARCHAR(5000) ;

PROCEDURE test 
AS
qry_select VARCHAR2(10000) := 'select
                t1.header_id 
                ,t1.flow_status_code 
            from  test_tblOOHA_Master t1;'; 
BEGIN
    v_cursor := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@times;
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@times(v_cursor,qry_select);
     WHILE DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@times(v_cursor) > 0
        LOOP 
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@times(v_cursor,1,header_id); 
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@times(v_cursor,2,flow_status_code); 

        qry  := 'UPDATE test_tblOOHA_Master  
                set  flow_status_code= "'|| flow_status_code ||'"
                where  header_id = '|| header_id ||' ;  ';

        dbms_output.put_line(qry);      
         /*
        qry variable generated the ff. string

        UPDATE test_tblOOHA_Master  
                set  flow_status_code= "TEST"
                where  header_id = 1603823 ;
       */

       num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@times (qry); -- When I stored the string to a variable, It throws and error

       num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@times (
                'UPDATE test_tblOOHA_Master  
                set  flow_status_code= "TEST"
                where  header_id = 1603823 ;'); -- But when I run the string directly, it works fine
    END LOOP;
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@times(v_cursor);
END test;

BEGIN
 test;
 COMMIT;
END;        
/
```

When I run the code I got this Error:

[image]

This part is where I am getting error:

```
 num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@times (qry); -- When I stored the string to a variable, It throws and error
```

But when run the string directly, it works fine.

```
num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@times (
                'UPDATE test_tblOOHA_Master  
                set  flow_status_code= "TEST"
                where  header_id = 1603823 ;'); -- But when I run the string directly, it works fine
```

Summary:
When using the variable `qry`, I got error. But when using direct string value, it works.

Whats wrong to my variable? Please help.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't.

Comment: Hi. I just improved my question to other subject as suggested by stackoverflow.

Comment: Aren't you are missing a space after `"TEST"` (which should be put in single quotes btw) and `WHERE` in the expression that builds the UPDATE statement?

Comment: The update statement executes here `num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@times (qry);`

Comment: space after the `"TEST"`?. No.The string is working. My only concern is the `qry` variable.When I put the string into variable before passing, I got the error.